# Is there a way to turn a web page into an app-like link on the android home page?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I'd like to be able to move to a specific page without having to (as I'm currently doing,) click on Chrome, then go to bookmarks and then have to go through the logon procedure to get back to the exact page I want.

Is there a way to have that precise page live as a pressable app-like icon so that I can get right back there quickly as I access this page often.

Comment: Have you tried the bookmark widget available with all Android installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmark the page in Chrome for Android. Go to your bookmarks, long-press on the bookmark, and click "Add to Home Screen".

Source:
http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57416489-285/how-to-add-chrome-for-android-bookmarks-to-your-home-screen/

Works on my Galaxy S4 and Nexus 7.

Comment: Champion Champion Champion

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Android Project.
In your Activity's `onCreate()` method write this code

```
String url = "http://www.your-link.com/; 
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

It will open an intent and show you all the browsers installed in your device. Just select any one and that will do. 
Chears !!